# Is there a way to export function names from IDA Pro?

Tags: ida

I need a way to copy all the function names of a binary which was dissassembled using IDA Pro. Is there an option for exporting functions from IDA?

Answer (score 3):

You can write a quick IDC script to enum function names and emit them to a text file.

Check idc.idc for the appropriate commands to use.

Another way is to simply open the Functions window and press Ctrl+C and paste the result in a file

Comment: I need to use `Ctrl+Ins` to copy the contents of the subview to the clipboard.

Answer (score 2):

GUI:

```
Ctrl+P > right menu > copy all
```

or
Py Script:

```py
import idautils, ida_funcs

def get_func_names():
    names = []
    for ea in idautils.Functions():
        name = ida_funcs.get_func_name(ea)
        names.append(name)
    return names

print('\n'.join(get_func_names()))
```

// tested with ida7

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I use to dump my function names, you'll want to change the 0x40000 to your first function EA value. Also you may want to change the output message. I right click on the output window and clear it, then run the script, then right-click save-as:

```
#include <idc.idc>

static FuncDump(start)
{
    auto ea, str, count, ref;
    auto end;
    auto teststr;

    ea = start;

    while( ea != BADADDR )
    {
        str = GetFunctionName(ea);
        if( str != 0 )
        {
            end = FindFuncEnd(ea);

            count = 0;
            ref = RfirstB(ea);
            while(ref != BADADDR)
            {
                count = count + 1;
                ref = RnextB(ea, ref);
            }

            teststr = sprintf("sub_%X", ea);
            if( teststr != str )
            {
                Message("-s 0x%X=%s\n", ea, str );
            }
            //Message("%s, 0x%d, 0x%x, 0x%x, 0x%x, %d\n", str, count, ea, end, end-ea, end-ea   );
        }

        ea = NextFunction(ea);
    }
}

static main() 
{
    //Message("FuncDump: Start\n");

    FuncDump(0x40000);

    //Message("FuncDump: Done\n");
}
```

Comment: How do you export the names from the output window? When I right click all I get are Copy/Clear. Also, I had to replace `sprintf()` with `form()` in order to get this working in IDA 5 Free

Comment: @crush in the paid versions there is a `save as` option, on the output window.

Comment: I highlight all the subroutines in the "Functions" window, and click the Edit menu, then Copy.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows DLL, there can be two or more functions associate with the same address with different ordinal numbers.

Scripting it one function per address is a wrong assumption.

The easier way to me was to export the program untouched by
File -> Produce File -> Create ASM file

and list out all occurrences of the string "Exported entry" with tools like "grep".

This works even with IDA Pro 5 free.

Certainly it will take sometime before analysis finishes.

Answer (score 0):

This simple script will export all names (not only function names) to python script which can be then imported in Ida:

```py
import idautils

print('import idaapi')
for ea in idautils.Names():
    print('idaapi.set_name(0x{:08X}, "{}")'.format(*ea))
```